# can we convert a live server to docker image

Tags: linux, docker, rhel

We are having a custom linux ( an RHEL spin-off) with security enhancements made to harden the box. Now we are planning to move to docker for dev-ops. Is there a way to convert the running box / ova / iso to docker? We are pretty new to docker and we tried to install on a rhel image step by step , it is difficult to harden again as we depend on 3rd party vendors.

Comment: Docker images are build with minimum / optimized file. You could any way do the setting in you image too by pulling publicly available images without much effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the steps mentioned in the link below,

[Convert Any Server to a Docker Container - By Zwischenzug](https://zwischenzugs.com/2016/04/04/convert-any-server-to-a-docker-container-updated/)

Here the author is talking about automating the whole process in couple of simple steps, in a nutshell,

1. Install ShutIt on the server.
2. Run the ‘copyserver’ ShutIt script.
3. Run your copyserver Docker image as a container.

[image: Automate Converting Any Server to a Docker Container]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is recommended to start over, you should be able to convert a running instance to docker image as described in official [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/baseimages/) with [bash script](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/contrib/mkimage-yum.sh) example for CentOS/RHEL.